# Handle Path Parameters from API call in WSO2 EI/ESB Integration Studio

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

I'm developing an API using WSO2 Integration Studio ESB Solution Project.

I'm calling this API from postman like "https://localhost:port/context/3542" where '3542' is the value of the path parameter being sent (let's say employeeId).

Further, I want to use this value (3542) in the http endpoint implemented in the same API to make a back-end call.

I'm not able to handle that path parameter. I tried using property mediator, didn't work.
Didn't find anything in the official documentation either.

Help appreciated. Thanks already.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [REST_URL_POSTFIX](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB470/HTTP+Transport+Properties#HTTPTransportProperties-Property:REST_URL_POSTFIXREST_URL_POSTFIX) property in order to use the value in the implementation. An example code segment is given below.

```
<property expression="$axis2:REST_URL_POSTFIX" name="Path"/>
```

Comment: I didn't need any property for that. I just kept the URI-template of API resource as /context/{empID}, and while calling backend, I directly gave endpoint as http://backend.com/{uri.var.empID}